# how to extract layout information from OCR image

Tags: python-3.x, ocr, tesseract, text-extraction

I would like to extract page layout information from PDF/scanned image for my OCR processing. is there any library in python can i use for this case ?

Regards,
MJ

Comment: What kind of information you are looking for? Please post example of your input, and desired output.